# Pandas counting rows with dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
      Date         X       Y
0  2002-01-01     ...     ...
1  2002-01-01     ...     ...
2  2002-01-03     ...     ...
3  2002-01-04     ...     ...
4  2002-01-04     ...     ...
5  2002-01-04     ...     ...
```

My goal is to get an additional column that count rows with the same dates and also drops duplicates:

```
      Date         X       Y      Count
0  2002-01-01     ...     ...       2
1  2002-01-03     ...     ...       1
2  2002-01-04     ...     ...       3
```

I've read a few posts and tried `.unique`, `.size()`, `.transform()`, `.value_counts()`, but none of them helped me through. Even simple `.drop_duplicates(subset='Date')` doesn't work.

Edit: the `Date` column was created with `.dt.date`.

Comment: `groupby('Date').size()` ?

Comment: To clarify, do you want one row per date? If so what do you expect to be displayed in the X, Y column?

Comment: X, Y don't matter to me. I only need to have counts of dates. And yes, one row per date.

Comment: probably your date not date type, check data type

Comment: @AhmedSunny `type(df['Date'][0]): <class 'datetime.date'>`.

Comment: then look at [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) this will help you do this

Comment: @AhmedSunny thanks, that's helpful, but how can I add a new column with these values?

Comment: Ok, what I did is:
`df['Count'] = 1` and 
`df.resample('D', on = 'Date').agg({'Count': np.sum})`
but there is no effect except for adding a column `Count`. I have absolutely no clue why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
a=df.groupby("Date").size().values
df= df.drop_duplicates(subset="Date").assign(Count=a)
```

Comment: Seems quite okay, although it dropped the whole Date column.

Comment: @alladinsane Which pandas version do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Start from computing how many times each date occurs:

```
cnt = df.groupby('Date').size().rename('Count')
```

The name given to *cnt* will be needed as the name of the respective
column in the result.

Then compute the result:

```
result = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Date')\
    .merge(cnt, left_on='Date', right_index=True)
```

The steps are:

- Drop duplicates (by default the first row is retained).
- Add *Count* column from *cnt*. Index values from *cnt* (dates)
  are matched with *Date* column.